# Showing Specific PivotItems Only

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a bit new to VBA, and I promise I performed a search but I'm afraid I'm too new to even search correctly as I am not sure of terms I may need.

I have a pivot table that is created as a part of a larger macro. Once created, I would like to only show specific PivotItems. Thus far, I'm seeing that I can only "hide" the ones I don't want to see. This won't work as I am pulling several similar (but slightly different) reports. Some don't share PivotItems and when running the macro I get an error as that item is missing. My code:

```
Sub PivotDetails()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Queue")
        .PivotItems("CAR").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("DOG").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("TRUCK").Visible = False

    End With
End Sub
```

So some of my reports have DOG, but some do not, so this will result in an error on the reports that don't even have the items to hide. All of the reports have items that I don't want to show, so it would be nicer if I could explicitly state the items I want.

Is this making any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each `PivotItem` in the `PivotField` and use a `Select` statement to determine if you want it to be visible or not.

The point is that you list all the items you want to show (or not show) and if the item does not exist in a given `PivotTable` it will be ignored as the name will never be passed into the Select statement.

```
Sub PivotDetails()

Dim ws As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem

Set ws = Sheets("mySheet") 'replace with your sheet name
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable5")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Qeue")

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems

    Select Case pi.Name

        Case Is = "CAR", "DOG", "TRUCK" 'add more values as needed

            pi.Visible = False

        Case Else

            pi.Visible = True

    End Select

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. This worked exactly as needed. Thank you so much.